# Navigating through Typescript references in Webstorm using ES6 module syntax

Tags: intellij-idea, reference, ide, typescript, webstorm

We are using Typescript with Intellij Webstorm IDE.

The situation is we use ES6 import syntax and `tsc` compiler 1.5.3 (set as custom compiler in Webstorm also with flag `--module commonjs`)

The problem is it is imposible to click through (navigate to) method from module (file)

```
// app.ts

import * as myModule from 'myModule';

myModule.myFunction();



// myModule.ts

export function myFunction() {
    // implementation
}
```

When I click on `.myFunction()` in `app.ts` I expect to navigate to `myModule.ts` file but this doesn't happen?

EDIT:

The way we exported functionality was bit different as in first example:

```
export: {
    myFunction1,
    myFunction2,
    // ...
};
```

Comment: works fine for me using WebStorm 10.0.4. What version do you use?

Comment: not at work right now, will check on monday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, my example in question was simplified too much. In real code we are using:

```
export: {
    myFunction1,
    myFunction2
    // ...
};
```

and this really doesn't work.

I have to change it to:

```
export function myFunction1() { /* impl */ }
export function myFunction2() { /* impl */ }
```

then it works.

Answer (score 1):

> When I click on .myFunction() in app.ts I expect to navigate to myModule.ts file but this doesn't happen

This is working fine in the current WebStorm release.

Comment: We are using Webstorm 10.0.4, when clicking the refference red notification is hown: `Cannot find declartion to go to`